# p-value equals zero for a bootstrapped sample

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, bootstrap

Suppose I want to test a null hypothesis that my sample mean $\bar{x}$ equals the parameter $\mu_0$. I perform bootstrapping on my sample and construct a $(1-\alpha)100\%$ confidence interval with the percentile method. But I find that even if I set $\alpha = 0$, the CI doesn't include the parameter $\mu_0$. Can I safely claim that for **ANY** confidence level $\alpha$, the null hypothesis is always being rejected, i.e, the p-value is 0?

Comment: Please describe in more detail what your procedure is. In particular, why do you have the population mean, and why are you testing anything if you *know* the population value?

Comment: Technically with $\alpha=0$, the interval should include all values.

Comment: @Dave Sorry my bad, I incorrectly used the true parameter. I've changed that, and the method I used for the CI was the percentile method.

Comment: @POC, yeah, I understand that it is true if the interval is constructed with the normal quantiles. But what I used was the percentile method, so when $\alpha = 0$, the CI was just the min and max of my bootstrapped sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not.

It it impossible that $p=0$. You can more safely assume that you can use an arbitrarely very high confidence interval and still reject the null hypothesis.

Theoretically, there should be an $\alpha$ for which the interval will eventually contain $\mu_0$.

This question is roughly related to researchers assuming $p=0$ because SPSS shows $p$-value at three digits, whereas it actually is $p < .001$.

Note that you should choose $\alpha$ before the bootstrap method making this question somewhat obsolete.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the computation of the p-value. Suppose I got a vector of bootstrapped statistics as $_1,_2, ..., _$, where $$ was the bootstrapped sample size. So for the p-value, I simply computed it as $2∗(\sum_{=1}^B(_<_0)/B,\sum_{=1}^B(_>_0)/B)$. All my $_$'s are greater than $_0$, so the p-value is 0. Is it wrong to compute it like this?

Comment: If you want a real $p$-value, you should compute $\frac{\bar{x}-\mu_0}{\text{sd}(x)}$.